# How do I reset the number of failed login attempts?

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to unlock the admin user of a drupal install using these instructions

http://www.aslingandastone.com/2011/how-to-reset-root-password-in-drupal-7-with-ftp-and-phpmyadmin/

But the user is blocked and email reset is not working:

> Sorry, there have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked. Try again later or request a new password.

Where in the database can I reset this blocked status? The admin user's status is set to '1' in the user's table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Drupal 7 prevents brute force attacks on accounts. It does so by refusing login attempts when more than 5 attempts failed. The amount of failed logins is recorded in the table 'flood'.

You can either wait before trying to login again, or clean the flood table following one of the procedures below:

1. Manually delete all of (or the last applicable) rows in 'flood' table.
2. Execute the following query on the Drupal database. To execute this query it will be necessary to login to the database. This is typically done through the command line or through a GUI interface such as phpMyAdmin.

   ```
   DELETE FROM `flood`;
   ```
3. From the command line, with drush installed, execute the following command:

   ```
   drush php-eval 'db_query("DELETE FROM `flood`");'
   ```

Comment: Have you really read nicoz' answer? He is not talking about the status column in the users table.